# BigQuery Put Query Result into Day Partition Table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

BigQuery can save query result into specify table, but If target table has day partition, currently I use Python loop query one day data and save to table, is other faster way?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two related feature requests that you can vote for and monitor progress - [`Update date-partitioned tables from results of a query`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905717) and [`Partition on non-date field`](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35905817)

Meantime, conceptually - the way you approach this - using loop - is correct and the only way as of now (August 2017)